# Curl to PHP with array, probably simple answer

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to curl in PHP... and I was just wondering how to transform this curl command into PHP:

```
curl  https://ancient-test.chargebee.com/api/v1/portal_sessions \
     -u test_rdsfgfgfddsffds: \
     -d customer[id]="EXAMPLE" \
     -d redirect_url="https://yourdomain.com/users/3490343"
```

Right now I've got:

```
$post_data['customer']['id']    = "EXAMPLE";
$post_data['redirect_url']      = "http://" . SITE_URL . "/myaccount/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://ancient-test.chargebee.com/api/v1/portal_sessions");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"test_rdsfgfgfddsffds:");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But I get the error message:

> {"errors":[{"message":"There were errors while submitting"},{"param":"customer[id]","message":"cannot be blank"}]}

Thanks for your help!

Jan

Comment: is `$customer['id']` empty?

Comment: Are you using Doctrine in your project?

Comment: php's curl extension doesn't handle multi.dimensional arrays (afaik). You should use `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));` or create the first-dimension array key by hand. However, your current code should generate an array-to-string conversion warning. Are you sure the code shown is the one you test with?

Comment: Thanks Rangad, that worked for me! The other two libraries require Composer, which I don't have on shared hosting.

Answer (score -1):

Using curl here's probably the answer [Posting with PHP and Curl, deep array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622448/posting-with-php-and-curl-deep-array?rq=1)

```
$post_data['customer[id]'] = "EXAMPLE";
```

---

[Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) is an awesome HTTP client library wrapping curl in PHP that will make your life way easier :)

With guzzle v6 your php code would look like this :

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://ancient-test.chargebee.com/api/v1/portal_sessions', [
    'auth' => ['test_rdsfgfgfddsffds', 'password'],
    'json' => [customer => [id => 'EXAMPLE']]
]);
```

Comment: Would love to use Guzzle, but it requires Composer... which I don't have in a shared hosting environment.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/CircleOfNice/CiRestClientBundle

This one has a beautiful api.

```
$client->post($url, $payload, $options);
```